# SQL Server 2012 query is not executing on test server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not able to execute a simple SQL query. When I'm using the `unlock` keyword, the record will open, but this keyword won't work if I want to truncate the table.

Please provide some suggestion how to solve this problem.

My query is shown here:

[image]

Comment: most probably the table is locked. Do the "EXEC sp_who2" and check who is blocking

Comment: Take note that your SPID is 156 -- this can be seen on your screen grab and it's part of the tab's name.  Read down the grid to SPID  156, and there is a column BlkBy - 'Blocked by.'  The number there is also a SPID.  You can look up that process on the same grid.  You'll see who owns it and what machine is running it, along with what the SQL is.  Hopefully that's enough context to determine your next steps (basically you can kill it or leave it alone for now).

Comment: the table is transaction so test team make a entry in it as it is showing insert cmd. and status is RUNNABLE.  it is the same table NOW how to change its status from RUNNABLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the query/process blocking your current query processing. There are many ways to identify Blocking. Here is one of the way.

```
Select *  from master.sys.sysprocesses
```

1. Column `Blocked` (Session ID) is Blocking the `SPID` column.
2. To see the Blocking query run `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<Blocked Session ID>)`

You can take appropriate action based on the value of column [Waittype, Open_Tran, and Status](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224453/inf-understanding-and-resolving-sql-server-blocking-problems).